# What does the | operator do?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what's the difference between ( | ) and ( || ) in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690512/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript)

I've seen this in a couple examples here but I never fully understood what it's supposed to do. Can anyone give me a simple example please?

Comment: Have a look at MDC: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/bitwise_operators#.7c_(Bitwise_OR)

Comment: Or see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690512/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, the `|` operator is a bitwise operators (in contrast to the `||` operator which is a logical operator).

It convert each operand to a 32-bit number, and performs a bitwise or between them.

Example of expressions and their results:

```
1 | 1 === 1
1 | 2 === 3
1.99 | 2.99 === 3
```

Reference: http://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/bitwise_operators

Comment: May I politely ask why you feel the need to litter our garden when _we're_ busy trying to tidy it?

Comment: I don't speak for @Guffa, but IMO, giving a good answer is never "litter", irrespective of the existence of duplicate questions.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: What on earth are you talking about? Besides, you failed miserably in asking politely...

Comment: @patrick dw: The 'litter' aspect comes into it when an answer is supplied to a redundant question, it wouldn't necessarily be litter in a more distinguished question to which is still relates.

Comment: ...IMO, giving a good answer is never "litter"...

Answer (score 2):

Depends where you use it:

- In regular expression it represents "or": `/[a-z]|[0-9]/i`
- It is also bitwise or operator, as described in: [What does the "|" (single pipe) do in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194950/single-pipe-in-javascript)