# Conditional assignment in JavaScript with Google Closure: | vs ||

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, variable-assignment, google-closure

I am using Google Closure and LOVE conditional assignments. I regularly use the

```
var stuff = (condition) ? opt0: opt1;
```

method and have more recently been introduced to

```
var stuff = opt_param || defaultValue;
```

But I have noticed a strange behavior, since it seems the

```
var stuff = opt_param | defaultValue;
```

is aslso working (i.e. with the single |), but this appears to "type cast" the variable into a number. I have not been able to find any documentation on this, so here's my question:

What is the difference between the single | and the double || in terms of logic and assignment? And is my assumption regarding the number type cast correct, or just an arbitrary product of the special case(s) I've been fiddling with?

Comment: I don't see how this question is related to the closure tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the difference between ( | ) and ( || ) in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690512/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Comment: You are absolutely right, Felix. I only thought it might, since the closure tools previously have been the only ones to tell me when I messed up in relation to "types"...
Also; As far as I've been able to figure, it's not possible to get any results on special characters like the |-pipe, so that might be why I had missed the previously posted question. My bad.

Comment: No worries :) Since the introduction of a new search engine, you can search for special characters by putting them in quotes, e.g. `[javascript] "|" "||"`.

Comment: Fantabulous! Will definitely be using that...! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly speaking, a single `|` refers to bitwise `OR` operator, which "performs the `OR` operation on each pair of bits. `a OR b` yields `1` if either `a` or `b` is `1`". Example from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7C_%28Bitwise_OR%29):

```
     9 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001001 (base 2)
    14 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001110 (base 2)
                   --------------------------------
14 | 9 (base 10) = 00000000000000000000000000001111 (base 2) = 15 (base 10)
```

While `||` is a logical `OR` that evaluates the first non-falsy statement in the assignment:

```
  123 || 0      === 123
false || "Text" === "Text"
   "" || true   === true
```

So basically these two operators are *not interchangeable* and may result in different values:

```
10 | 2  === 10
10 || 2 === 10
```

... however,

```
9 | 14  === 15
9 || 14 === 9
```

Answer (score 1):

`|` is bitwise OR:

```
3 | 4 = 7
0xFF00FF | 0x00FF00 = 0xFFFFFF
```

`||` is logical OR, evaluates to the first argument if it is *true*, otherwise the second:

```
3 || 4 = 3
0 || 4 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `||` operator is short-circuit OR. It assigns the first if it is true-like or the second.  `|` on the other hand is Bit-wise operator. It performs a bitwise OR on the two parameters. If the first one evaluates to `0` result of bit-wise OR will be the second parameter.

It will give wrong results when both are numbers. Better go with `||`.

Please have a look at [Bitwise Operators on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).